# Transforming scheme into CPS to desugar call/cc

Tags: compiler-construction, scheme, cps

context:
I'm currently writing a small scheme compiler and took the approach of first transforming into administrative normal form and then into cps (I find this to be the easiest to understand, since there is a clear seperation in what they do).

the question:
CPS uses continuations only for non-primitives and not for primitives. I really don't understand the connection between this and being able to correctly desugar call/cc and the likes. Wouldn't it be enough to simply create a lambda for each call/cc, which represents the continuation? Why are we using continuations for all the non-primives / Have I wrongly assumed CPS being a necessity to be able to desugar call/cc?

example:

```
(+ 2 (call/cc (lambda (k) (k 2))))
```

becomes (anf)

```
(let ((v1 (call/cc (lambda (k) (k 2)))))
    (+ 2 v1))
```

becomes (continution for call/cc as well as its desugaring)

```
((λ (f cc) (f (λ (x _) (cc x)) cc)) (lambda (k cont) (k 2))
   (lambda (v1) ((lambda (x) (display-or-whatever x)) (+ 2 v1)))))
```

I'd assume this approach generally works.

Comment: Ok, I'm in. What would `(let ((c 11) (r (call/cc (lambda (exit) exit)))) (if (procedure? r) (r 7) (+ r c)))` look like with just lambdas and no CPS conversion? Will it still evaluate to `18`?

Comment: @Sylwester Thanks for your Answer!  The correct transformation would be 
```(let ((c1 11))
  ((lambda (f cc) (f (lambda (x _) (cc x)) cc)) (lambda (exit cont) (cont exit))
   (lambda (r)
     (let ((c2 (procedure? r)))
       (if c2
           (halt (r 7))
           (halt (+ r c1)))))))```
So in order for call/cc and the likes to work, I need to never return but instead use a chain of function calls thus needing to add the continuation to all non primitives which will be called in tail position. Correct me if I'am wrong.